# Wordpress homepage only works when permalink is set to page id

Tags: wordpress

[image]My issue is that WordPress homepage only works when permalink is set to page-id but other pages doesn't work from header menu. And if I change permalink settings to postname, header menu pages works and homepage breaks. Attaching screenshot for the same.
I am doing this on staging server. Also its a multi-site.
Please help.TIA.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Select Post Name in Setting > Permalinks.

Comment: As i mentioned in my query, if i select postname, homepage breaks

Comment: Try This "<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">Home Page or Logo</a>"